# how to get livereload working with grunt?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-connect

I am getting my head around grunt and trying to run my site through grunt and connect. 
I have a gruntfile like this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({

    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    connect: {
      options: {
        port: 9000,
        // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
        hostname: 'localhost',
        livereload: 35729
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          open: true,
          middleware: function (connect) {
            return [
              connect.static('.tmp'),
              connect().use(
                '/bower_components',
                connect.static('./bower_components')
              ),
              connect.static(appConfig.app)
            ];
          }
        }
      }
  });

  // Load the plugin that provides the "uglify" task.
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');

  // Default task(s).
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['connect:livereload','watch']);

};
```

The problem is when I run grunt I get an error:

```
Running "connect:livereload" (connect) task
Warning: undefined is not a function Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

How can I get grunt running ?

Comment: run `grunt --verbose` You will get more informantion of the error.

Comment: is `appConfig.app` defined?

Answer (score 1):

I can see that you call `appConfig.app` (probably c/p from a yeoman generated project) but you never created it. That could be a hint, because the rest of your code seems correct.

Answer (score 0):

In the project I am currently working on I decided to change the plugin to BrowserSync. It is easy to configure and does its' job.

BrowserSync website: http://www.browsersync.io/docs/grunt/.
The configuration is easy and it is given on their website so I am not going to copy it here. Maybe if you have difficulties with `grunt-contrib-connect` you can try this one.